# Moq: How to verify that an Action<T> argument is an empty function?

Tags: c#, automapper, moq

In Automapper v9, the `Map()` method has the following signature:

```
TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source, Action<IMappingOperationOptions> opts);
```

We often do the following usage:

```
_mapper.Map<SomeClass>(srcObj, _ => { });
```

**Question**: With Moq, how do I test that the second argument really is an empty `Action`?

I know how to ignore the second argument, but that's not really a good test...

```
_mapper.Setup(m => m.Map<SomeClass>(srcObj, It.IsAny<Action<IMappingOperationOptions>>()))
       .Returns(mapped);
```

*Bonus point*: how would I test a non-empty `Action`?

Comment: Why are you passing an empty `Action`? Can't you use the `Map` method without the `Action` parameter? `TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source)`

Comment: You would think so, but not always, no: see https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3206

Comment: You might need something to do with `action.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray()`.

Comment: But if you're not setting anything when you call Map, why do you need the context?

Comment: @Lucian, I don't know ;) Sometimes I do, sometimes I don't. Whenever my mapping is like `_mapper.Map<ApiResponse<ObjectPayload[]>>(src);`, I need it since v9.

Comment: You're creating problems for yourself :) When you use the context, you must be setting smth at Map time. So you use the right overload anyway. Otherwise you must be doing smth weird and you should probably stop.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Ah, that may be ;) It is probably because sometimes I use `opts.Items` to support "sparse fieldset mapping" in the `ApiResponse`, so I need to check if the context contains any sparse field definition (if not there, map everything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can analyse the action method's compiled (IL) code to determine if it was empty:

```
private bool IsEmptyAction(Action<IMappingOperationOptions> a)
{
    return a.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray().SequenceEqual(new byte[] { 0x0, 0x2a });
}
```

The `0x0, 0x2a` value was obtained through observation of what the IL looks like for an empty action. It ws the same for both an action with generic type arguments, and an action with none.

Then you can use this method like so:

```
It.Is<Action<IMappingOperationOptions>>(a => IsEmptyAction(a))
```

And obviously testing the opposite is just a case of negating the condition (`!IsEmptyAction(a)`).

To test the options for certain values, you'll probably need to mock `IMappingOperationOptions`:

```
private bool IsItemsExist(Action<IMappingOperationOptions> a, Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool> itemsChecker)
{
    // Create mock of options
    var optionsMock = new Mock<IMappingOperationOptions>();
    var itemsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    optionsMock.SetupGet(o => o.Items).Returns(itemsDictionary);

    // Call action
    a(optionsMock.Object);

    // Call check function
    return itemsChecker(itemsDictionary);
}
```

Then you can apply this to your main mock:

```
test
    .Setup(t => t.TestMethod(It.Is<Action<IMappingOperationOptions>>(a => !IsItemsExist(a, d => d.ContainsKey("test")))))
    .Throws(new Exception("must contain test"));
```

And then you can test it like so:

```
test.Object.TestMethod(o => o.Items.Add("test", "moo"));
Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => test.Object.TestMethod(o => o.Items.Add("hello", "test")));
```

Of course this is just an example, so you can make it more or less generic, etc. as you need to.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote? OP asked how to determine if an action is empty. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I upvoted just to counter the downvote.  Seemed silly without an explanation.

Comment: @Xipooo Appreciated. Even if we don't agree with what OP is doing, this might still be useful for someone else. I can imagine test scenarios where you might want to ensure that an empty action isn't passed.

Comment: For the record, I wasn't the downvoter (I upvoted too). Your solution seems to work for empty functions. Thanks. My "bonus" question was about testing something more specific than "not empty". Something like `opts => opts.Items.Add(...)`, but maybe I can figure something out.

Comment: @dstj In that case I guess you'd actually have to call the action in the `Is` method with a mocked `IMappingOperationOptions` object.

Comment: @John, will try, thanks. Oh, and I don't agree either with what I asked! ;) But Automapper v9 throws an `InvalidOperationException` (in my complex mapping scenario) without that empty function argument... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @dstj Now I've understood the other part of your question properly, I've made an edit which hopefully answers it.